# Get interrupt on plugging in android usb on windows

Tags: android, c++, usb, adb, interrupt

Is there a way I can get a notification to my C++ code if I plug in an android device to my windows PC.

Something like an interrupt or a broadcast message windows sends on an event of plugging an android device would help.

I am currently running adb and check the output to see if any device is connected on adb through C++ at an interval.

Comment: I came across a library called ddmlib in java doing this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17381324/how-to-tell-if-android-device-detected-by-adb . Does anybody know anout a similer c++ library?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have found a solution.

I opened a socket listening to ADB on port 5037 and send host:track-devices

Now whenever a device is registered with ADB I get the device details in the socket stream.